# How to scanf one string, a pipe, and then another string all without any break/space in between?

Tags: c, string, input, scanf

The user will enter the configuration of the bus, like this

```
2
OO|XO
XX|XX
```

where

- the number in the first line (let **n**) tells the number of rows, and
- the following **n** lines show a pair of two seats
- with a walkway in between denoted by **`|`**, a pipe.
- A seat can either be occupied or empty. An empty seat is denoted by an **O**; an occupied one by an **X**.

---

```
char str1[3], str2[3];
```

I'm treating each pair of seats as a string,

```
char pipe;
```

and the pipe as a character.

I tried doing this:

```
scanf("%s %*c %s", str1, pipe, str2);
```

and this:

```
scanf("%s", str1);
pipe = getchar();
scanf("%s", str2);
```

but still no luck.

The question is: **How to enter two/more characters/strings in one go without separating them with any kind of space or break?**

Comment: Use maximum field width.

Comment: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: The `"%s"` format in [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) reads *space-delimited* strings. Since you have no space in the input the first `"%s"` reads *all* of the line.

Answer (score 2):

First, read the property of `%s` conversion specifier. The input is delimited by a whitespace, not by a pipe `|`, at least not automatically.

The easiest workaround would be, to use a **[maximum field width](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)**, something like

```
scanf("%2s%*c%2s", str1, str2);  // the * in %*<CS> indicates assignment suppression,
                                 // you don't need a corresponding argument at all, and
                                 // a wrong one will cause trouble
```

here, you don't need to modify the code if you wish to chose a different *delimiter*, it'll consider *anything* as a delimiter. If you want to enforce the use of `|`, you can write

```
scanf("%2s|%2s", str1, str2);
```

**NOTE** - never forget to check the return value of `scanf()` to ensure success.

Answer (score 2):

`scanf` lets you specify any separator that you wish to use, including pipe. Since the pipe is always there, you don't need to scan it into your program, instead instructing `scanf` to skip it:

```
char a[3], b[3];
scanf("%2s|%2s", a, b);
printf("'%s' '%s'", a, b);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/ScHHoN)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 different ways to address your problem:

- If the string length is fixed, you can just specify the maximum number of characters to read for `%s` and use this code:

  ```
  char str1[3], str2[3];
  if (scanf("%2s|%2s", str1, str2) == 2) {
      /* read 2 characters into str1, a pipe and 1 or 2 characters into str2 */
  }
  ```
- If the string length is variable, such as on planes with different numbers of seats in some rows, you can use a scanset `%[OX]` and also specify the number of characters to read to prevent potential buffer overflow on unexpected input. Here is an example:

  ```
  char str1[5], str2[5];  // handle up to 4 seats on each side */
  if (scanf("%4[OX]|%4[OX]", str1, str2) == 2) {
      /* read a group of 1 to 4 `X` or `O` into str1 and str2, separated by | */
  }
  ```

You can add another conversion to further verify that the line has the expected format.  Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char buf[128];
    int i, n, c;
    char left[3], right[3];

    if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid format, empty file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (sscanf(buf, "%d %c", &n, &c) != 1 || n < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid format, expected positive number: %s\n", buf);
        return 1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "missing %d lines\n", n - i);
            return 1;
        }
        if (sscanf(buf, "%2[XO]|%2[XO] %c", left, right, &c) != 2) {
            fprintf(stderr, "invalid format: %s\n", buf);
            return 1;
        } else {
            printf("row %d: %s | %s\n", i + 1 + (i >= 12), left, right);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```